# Timeout error when calling external API from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, connection-timeout

I have the following index.js(node v19.6.0) with POST request that calls external API and register a webhook. The url of the hook I am registering already works and tested it.

I googled the error but I couldn't find any results. The error comes when I call /register/hook method. It shows that there is a timeout but doesn't give me much more detail. Is the issue from the API provider or the way I am making REST calls ?

The code was generated by [Alchemy](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/sdk-create-webhook).

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
})

app.post("/register/hook", (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          accept: 'application/json',
          'X-Alchemy-Token': 'abc...def',
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          AddressWebhookParams: {addresses: ['0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564']},
          url: 'https://webhook.site/dfb04cab-8ca9-40f1-a522-66918d4a7015',
          type: 'ADDRESS_ACTIVITY'
        })
      };
      
      fetch('https://alchemy-sdk-core-example.com/create-webhook', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
})
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12789:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
      at onConnectTimeout (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8236:28)
      at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8194:50
      at Immediate._onImmediate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8225:13)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:475:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
  }
}

  [1]: https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/sdk-create-webhook
```

Comment: What Node.js version are you using?

Comment: I am using node v19.6.0

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding

```js
import { fetch, setGlobalDispatcher, Agent } from 'undici'
...
setGlobalDispatcher(new Agent({ connect: { timeout: 60_000 } }) )
```

before my `fetch` to configure the timeout. Of course you should first install [`undici`](https://github.com/nodejs/undici)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't send back a response from your handler, the client will wait indefinitely, or until it gives up:

```
      fetch('https://alchemy-sdk-core-example.com/create-webhook', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
        .finally(() => res.end()); // end the response process
```

More info [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end).

Answer (score -1):

Double check url and parameters, everything else seems fine. It usually has timeout issue if url does not exist or maybe their servers are temporarily down.
Also I would recommend using axios. It would avoid you trouble like setting extra content headers.

Comment: I see. I can use axios as well. Btw I tried to add timeout parameter on the session and made it longer, but once the time out is over, I still got same error. Will try your suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't do anything. I just switched to WiFi. :)

Comment: try be helpful and avoid sarcasm